# Multiplication by identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is any legal multiplication by identity matrix equal to the original matrix,

$$ A_{n\times m}  I_m = A_{n\times m} $$
$$ I_n A_{n\times m}   = A_{n\times m} $$

I mean is it always right?

Comment: Yep, always.${}$

Comment: Why not multiply it out for yourself and check that it is so? Where's the problem>

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you

Comment: @ancientmathematician because I can somehow miss some case, that it isn't right

Comment: But you know the formula for the $(i,j)$-element of $AB$ surely? If you write down your attempt at a proof then people may help ...

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm not looking for a proof, I just want to know if it's right

Comment: Alas, we only know things are right when we can prove them.

Comment: Why do you think the identity matrix has that name?

Comment: @ancientmathematician so many times math proof is wrong... e.g. Marjorie Rice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is why it is called the identity matrix. Any matrix multiplied by the identity matrix is the original matrix, just as the multiplicative identity for $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$.

For an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, we have $$(AI)_{ij} = A_{i1}I_{1j}+A_{i2}I_{2j}+\dots+A_{in}I_{nj}$$
But $I_{ij}=0$ when $i \neq j$ and 1 otherwise. So $(AI)_{ij} = A_{ij}$. We get 
$$\begin{align}(AI)_{ij} &= A_{i1}I_{1j}+A_{i2}I_{2j}+\dots+A_{ij}I_{jj}+\dots+A_{in}I_{nj} \\
&= A_{i1}\cdot0+A_{i2}\cdot0+\dots+A_{ij}\cdot1+\dots+A_{in}\cdot0\\
&=A_{ij}\end{align}$$

Showing $(IA)_{ij} = A_{ij}$ is similar.